# Escaping a single curly brace when formatting a Python string

Tags: python

Is it possible in Python to have a single, unmatched curly brace in a format string? I know that I can use double matched braces to print a single matched brace but I can't express just a single brace without my intent being ambiguous.

```
'{{}} {}'.format(42) # Yields '{} 42' - this is not what I'm asking about
'{ %d' % 42 # Yields '{ 42' - this is what I want, but with the format syntax
'{{} {}'.format(42) # Not valid because the braces are unmatched
'\{ {}'.format(42) # Not valid because escaped brace characters are not supported
```

I fear that this ability does not exist in Python, but I would like confirmation. I suspect I will have to resort to using a different type of formater (the % syntax) or string concatenation.

Comment: Can you clarify what output you want to get? `{ 42`?

Comment: Yes, '{ 42' is the desired output

Comment: `"{{ {}".format(34)`?

Comment: '{' +'{0}'.format(42) if you want  '{42'

Comment: That's it! For some reason I didn't think to try unmatched double braces. Thanks!

Comment: I was about to answer, and you closed it too fast :P